# Calulate total time taken by a UNIX job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scope

I have a shell script that is used to run a sequence of jobs(say 1 to 50) in UNIX environment.
I need to calculate the total time taken by the script to complete the whole task(all 50 jobs). I tried using the SECONDS variable to calculate the total time but the variable gets reset to 0 again if any of the jobs fail in the middle (job failure means we have to re trigger the script and it will continue from the job it failed at say at job 10). The variable TOTALTIME stores only the time from last unsuccessful job.I want to retain the time variable till all the jobs are completed. I am new to shell scripting and need a help to fix this issue.

```
SECONDS=0
while CONDITION
do
job 1
job 2
.
.
.
job 50
done
TOTALTIME=$SECONDS
echo "Total time : $(($TOTALTIME/ 3600)) hours, $((($TOTALTIME/ 60)%60)) minutes, and $(($TOTALTIME% 60)) seconds " >> abc.log
```

Comment: `time /path/to/my/bigWrapperScript args to script` ? Other wise, try saving the `SECONDS` value to a tmp file before you start each portion of the main script. That will take some work. Is this really worth the trouble? Good luck

Comment: Include how you restart the script too.

Comment: @oguzismail script is started manually again (same way as in the beginning)

Comment: @shellter could you please explain the first option you provided.. "time /path/to/my/bigWrapperScript args to scrip"

Comment: do a simple test. `time sleep 5`. I hadn't read your Q carefully when I posted that idea. It only captures the time of the cmd supplied as an argument. It may still help your issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `date` and `epoc` time?

```
SECONDS=$(date "+%s")
while CONDITION
do
job 1
job 2
.
.
.
job 50
done
TOTALTIME=$(date "+%s")
echo "Total time : $(( (($TOTALTIME - $SECONDS))/ 3600)) hours, $((( (($TOTALTIME - $SECONDS))/ 60)%60)) minutes, and $(( (($TOTALTIME - $SECONDS)) %  60)) seconds " >> abc.log
```